# It is impossible to parse json (Ion)

Tags: android, android-json, android-ion

I use my library Projects [enter link description here](https://github.com/koush/ion)

The author gives an example:

```
public static class Tweet {
    public String id;
    public String text;
    public String photo;
}

public void getTweets() throws Exception {
    Ion.with(context)
    .load("http://example.com/api/tweets")
    .as(new TypeToken<List<Tweet>>(){})
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<Tweet>>() {
       @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<Tweet> tweets) {
          // chirp chirp
        }
    });
}
```

I do follow his example. But is not clear in what form the data come in Example.
I make the example:

```
public static class Test {
        public String name;
        public String soname;
        public String age;
        public String country;
    }
    private void setData(){
        Ion.with(getActivity())
                .load("http://........")
                .as(new TypeToken<List<Test>>(){})
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<Test>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<Test> result) {
                        // do stuff with the result or error
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.get(0).name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

but get an error:

```
12-22 05:46:59.609      414-414/com.testlist.pavel.transportercity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.testlist.pavel.transportercity.Fragments.Kitchen_list_of_orders$1.onCompleted(Kitchen_list_of_orders.java:49)
            at com.testlist.pavel.transportercity.Fragments.Kitchen_list_of_orders$1.onCompleted(Kitchen_list_of_orders.java:45)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:79)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:105)
            at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:215)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:171)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

help to understand what is the problem? my answer from the server:

```
{"name":"Vasya","soname":"Pupkin","age":"25","country":"Russian Federation"}{"name":"Iliya","soname":"Strelnikov","age":"43","country":"Kazahstan"}
```

Maybe not the correct data format and the library can not they understand?

Comment: is your response complete, because its showing json format error in
jsonLint

Comment: the fact that the example does not specify which row gets author. and so I can not understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `Ion` library expects to receive an `JsonArray` from the url. Make sure you get `JsonArray`. Secondly `result.get(0).name` would return `null pointer` sometimes, the reason being one should first check if there is any error happened during the request. This can be found via the parameter `e` in `onCompleted` method. Then you need to check if the `List` has elements before sending it to a toast, coz if `0th element` is `not found` then you are gonna get a null pointer error.

Do something similar to below in `onCompleted` method.

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<Test> result) {

   //do stuff with the result or error
   String msg;
   if(e != null) {
       msg = "Error occured";
   }else if(result.size()>0){
       msg = "Received 0 elements";
   }else{
       msg = result.get(0).name;
   }

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: 12-22 06:08:41.218      577-577/com.testlist.pavel.transportercity D/ionmy﹕ Error occured
the fact that the example does not specify which row gets author. and so I can not understand.

Comment: i could not understand ur comment :-/

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: I want to say that I do not understand how the line should look like that I get from the server. in my case

Comment: well the error shows that it expects an jsonArray while it got was jsonObject. Make sure your url returns jsonArray. An jsonArray should have the format `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: I try so, but still error [{"name":"Vasya","soname":"Pupkin","age":"25","country":"Russian Federation"},{"name":"Iliya","soname":"Strelnikov","age":"43","country":"Kazahstan"},{"name":"Iliya","soname":"Lagutenko","age":"49","country":"Ukraine"}]